# What facebook permission does my app need to post to a facebook user's feed asynchronously or when the user is offline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tested with  "publish_stream" permission, and my app can publishes an item to the user's feed with this permissiom. But there is a major  problem with this

When the  "publish_stream" permision is reqisted, it frightens the users because the Facebook warning or prompt is scarry : "**Post to Facebook as me**. .... may post status messages, notes, photos, and videos **on my behalf**"

For a lot of users, this is a deal breaker. They do not want anyone posting as them

b) I became of fan of TopGear and CBSnews -- these applications are able to post news to my newfeed  -- without me giving them "publish_stream" permission.

So what is the best permission to use for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

publish_stream is required for the app to publish as the user to the users feed via the graph api.  No permission is required if you are using the javascript FB.ui method of publishing because the user has the option of typing in their own message and/or cancelling it.

If you become a fan of a page, those pages aren't publishing updates as you.  You are simply seeing their updates in your home page stream.  Your friends won't see those updates unless they also become a fan of that page.

Comment: Hi ,is it possible to use offline_access permission to do the same ? Our user testing has indicated that the "As me" in the warning/permission prompt turns away a lot of our prospective users. The javascript FB.ui method  is not an option in my case.

Comment: No, to publish to their stream you need publish_stream. You could only ask for basic to start with and then later ask for it as you need it and once they trust your app.